# Image repository web for 3rd people uploads

Tags: image, repository

I am searching for a **website where I can upload images** in a folder of the repository, and **other people (people unknown) can upload images in the same folder, without deleting the existing files**.

I thought about **GitHub** but is quite complex maybe for new people.
I tried **Google Drive**, but it does not work as I want: if I give permission to 3rth people to edit, I can not protect the current files to be eliminated.

Does anybody have a suggestion about it?